# How to vertically center a text irrespective of the content

Tags: html, css

I have three div elements having the same styles.the content inside the div is dynamic as you can see below

**Current**

[image]

how to make the text center inside each div like below

**Expected**

[image]

```css
.sample{
     padding:15px;
    width:150px;
    height:70px;
    float: left;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#3498db;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    text-align:left;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:normal;
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sample"> Some text </div>
<div class="sample"> A little more text is added </div>
<div class="sample"> This text is large compared to other sample divs </div>
```

Comment: Your answer should be found in a previous thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461521/how-to-center-an-element-horizontally-and-vertically.

Comment: using `display:flex;` . but why you use `text-align:left` and also `text-align:center` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using flex is very simple. All you have to do is add: *display: flex*, *align-items: center* and *justify-content: center*

```css
.sample{
     padding:15px;
    width:150px;
    height:70px;
    float: left;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#3498db;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    text-align:left;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:normal;
    margin-right:10px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="sample"> Some text </div>
<div class="sample"> A little more text is added </div>
<div class="sample"> This text is large compared to other sample divs </div>
```

Comment: Code dropping is frowned upon .. Please EXPLAIN your answer ..

Comment: It seems fine here.